# Positioning 2 DIVs under one DIV

Tags: html, css

I am making a page with responsive layout. I can not manage to put 2 DIVs under one DIV element. I tried Flexbox, Float and other solutions from here.

col-1,col-2 and col-3 are all inside .three-col div

Here is the CSS:

```
.three-col {
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    flex-direction: row;
}


  @media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    body {
      background-color: yellow;

    }
    !!!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
    .col-2
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-3
    {
        float:left; 
        clear: left;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .three-col {
        margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
        display: flex;
    }
  }

.col-1, .col-2, .col-3 {
    padding: 20px;
}

.col-1 {
    background-color: lightpink;
}

.col-2 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.col-3 {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

This is how it should look like in the middle case from the CSS file:

[image: Expected result]

HTML model:

```
<body>
    <div class="three-col">
        <div class="col-1">
            <h1>Column One</h1>
            <p>
                Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
                .</p>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum 
                from a line in section 1.10.32.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <h2>Column Two</h2>
            <p>There ng this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200
                Latr, or
                non-characteristic words etc.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <h2>Column Three</h2>
            <p>Iibution
                of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like reglish.</p>
            <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their .</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well please. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is using flexbox. Also keep in mind this is invalid css '!!!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!', and it may prevent parsing.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.three-col {
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .three-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .col-1 {
    width: 100%
  }
  .col-2, .col-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .three-col {
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    display: flex;
  }
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-1 {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.col-3 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="three-col">
    <div class="col-1">
        <h1>Column One</h1>
        <p>
            Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
            .</p>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum 
            from a line in section 1.10.32.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <h2>Column Two</h2>
        <p>There ng this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200
            Latr, or
            non-characteristic words etc.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <h2>Column Three</h2>
        <p>Iibution
            of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like reglish.</p>
        <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their .</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: but now when it passes 600 px it doesn't go back, it is supposed to have all the DIVs in a row

Comment: My question is what should I add in the last @media to have all DIVs on a single row?

Comment: Check this out https://codepen.io/fromaline/pen/zYBoEOQ You need to specify the `flex-wrap: nowrap` and make divs back 100% width

Comment: Thank you, sir. You saved me.